# Обработка события клика одного из ImageView элемента ListView

Tags: android

Т.е. есть список, элемент которого состоит из двух ImageView. Нужно сделать их обработчики клика. Сделал обработчик элемента в целом а как тут незнаю. Обработчик элемента так:

```
lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            openMSG(id);

        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно создать собственный адаптер для ЛистВью, и в нем в переопределенном методе getView подпихивать свой лэйаут, как раз с двумя картинками, там его разбирать, доставать оттуда через findViewById свои картинки, и от уже им назначать слушатели. Наверное не очень понятно, попробуйте разобрать пример [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter), как раз работа с картинками в ListView

Comment: Я реализовал список уже со своим лэйаутом как тут http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html и получаю клик по элементу. Новичок в этом не охота все переделывать. Может можно как то реализовать там?

Comment: Как вариант попробуйте ясно указать методы, отвечающие на нажатие, в файле item.xml, в атрибуте onClick, и создать этот метод в активити, тут пример - http://terokarvinen.com/2011/simple-button-for-android-xml-onclick-public-method

Comment: Гарантировать не могу, возможно сработает. Если нет - все таки придется расширять класс SimpleCursorAdapter c переопределенным методом getView

Comment: Попробовал сделать так: lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                switch (view.getId()) { но тут RelativeLayout

Comment: Все верно, таким образом слушатель обрабатывает нажатие на строку списка, но вот о ImageView на ней о ничего не знает, и обработать именно клик на ней не дает

Comment: мда... мне нужно то знать по какой картинке кликнули и id